# Clean architecture and Repository pattern

Tags: repository-pattern, clean-architecture

I'm working in a new project and I'm trying to use the Clean Architecture approach with Repository pattern. I'm using .net core 3, C#, Automapper, MediatR and Dapper.

I have these layers:

Domain (in the center, the core of all): here I have the business Entities, Aggregations and Value Objects with their validations rules and exceptions;

Application (it's around the Domain): here I'm using CQRS patterns and I have my Commands, Queries and Interfaces;

Persistence: here I have the implementations of the repositories interfaces.

I red that a repository should be responsible of the all CRUD operations relative to one table in the database. For this I want to know how I should implement the repositories for an ENTITY that is an AGGREGATION ENTITY. Should I create an AGGREGATION REPOSITORY that extract data from different tables? Or should I have a repository for each table and a SERVICE that creates AGGREGATION using more than one repository?

Thanks

Comment: "I red that a repository should be responsible of the all CRUD operations relative to one table in the database." This not true. You do not have to have a one-repository-to-one-table relationship.

Comment: @EricKing ok, but when you have AGGREGATION entity how do you do? Do you implement CRUD operations for different tables in the same repository?

Comment: Yes. If you have an Orders repository and you need to return Orders along with their OrderDetails, then you do whatever data access you need in the Orders repository. If you never get OrderDetails without the corresponding Order, then you don't need an OrderDetails repository. No need to put an arbitrary limitation on it.

Comment: I came across this article which enforces creating one repo per aggregation. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design

Answer (score 5):

A good repository should abstract away the underlying database structure. An entity may have its data stored in several different tables, but your domain logic shouldn't care about that. At most, you'd have one repository for each entity in your domain, but you could also just have one repository for each aggregate root. It's up to you to decide what makes sense for your case.

For example, let's say your domain contains Order entities and OrderLineItem entities. Does it make sense in your domain to retrieve an OrderLineItem directly without the corresponding Order? If so, then you may need a repository for both entities. However, if you only access OrderLineItem entities from an Order entity, then you only need a repository for Orders. This repository would potentially query both the orders table and the order line items table to construct a complete Order with all of its OrderLineItems.

Comment: OK, this is clear but there is still a doubt. Imagine if I have an aggregate root that inside has entity that I need to manipulate also out of the aggregation. In this case I'll have distinct repository for each entity. It means that in each repository I'll have a GET method to take the data from the database.  But where should I put the method that I'll use to get the entire aggregation? Should I have an AGGREGATION REPOSITORY (SERVICE, FACTORY... I don't know) that use the others repositories?

Comment: @ChristianCascone this is exactly the issue you'll keep coming across with the repository pattern in general - it defines arbitrary boundaries that become ambiguous and confusing in all but the most trivial cases. This is why I generally prefer to just define the contracts for a particular query by the client and then just write whatever query satisfies that contract. I have never seen the "repository pattern" as particularly beneficial. In fact a CRUD repository is anti-CQRS, the whole point of which is to decouple your queries from your write model.

Comment: @AntP I want to separate the PERSISTENCE layer from DOMAIN and I want to test my logic without a database. For this I need to define an INTERFACE in my DOMAIN layer and the implementation of this it will be in PERSISTENCE layer. To follow your advice, I should have my GetUserQueryHandler (in DOMAIN) and inside this I'll have an entity that implements IGetUserQuery (DOMAIN) that has the method to extract my data. In my PERSISTENCE layer I'll implement each of this INTERFACE, Is it correct?

Comment: @ChristianCascone I take issue with the idea that you need interfaces in your domain to separate persistence. For example, you can make queries from an orchestration or service layer and then populate your domain with values instead of injecting your persistence into your domain. What I'm saying is that when it comes to reading data, just write whatever query you need to get the data that you need, don't try and shoehorn everything into a particular model.

Comment: @AntP isn't clear this for me. I'll try to explain better. You are putting another layer in the middle to do things that my APPLICATION layer does. In my APPLICATION layer I have queries and commands. All of these work with the entities of my DOMAIN layer. In the handlers of the queries and the commands I need to access to my PERSISTENCE layer to get and put data. To separate the APPLICATION from the PERSISTENCE I need interfaces otherwise my APPLICATION will be strongly coupled with the kind of the database/ORM that I'll chose to use. So the question is with CQRS how can I do this?

Comment: @ChristianCascone I'll repeat again - your domain doesn't need persistence interfaces to decouple it from your persistence implementation. You can achieve that by making your domain pure and value-driven and not having a persistence dependency in your domain at all. Also, interfaces do not really decouple anything in this sense - that is an illusion.

Comment: @AntP how can you persist your data if you don't have in your domain something that can do this operation? Give me an example, a link where I can find your idea of architecture

Comment: @ChristianCascone by keeping your domain pure and passing values to it from an orchestrator or service.

Comment: @AntPand this orchestrator or service how can take the data from the database?